# I am getting a out of memory error in flutter after playing 15 to 20 videos using preloadpageview

Tags: flutter, dart, out-of-memory

I am developing an application in flutter, I am using a preloadpageview and cached video player plugin to play videos by urls from my database, after playing 15 to 20 videos, my app is shutting down and logcat is prompting error like this. I am initialising a video in initstate and disposing the video widget as well.

video widget code:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = CachedVideoPlayerController.network(mediaUrl);
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = controller.initialize();
    controller.setLooping(true);
  }


  buildvideopreview(){
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return Stack(fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
              AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VisibilityDetector(
                    key: Key(postId),
                    onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo info){
                      print("${info.visibleFraction} of my widget is visible");
                        if(info.visibleFraction == 1 && controller != null){
                          print('===========playing');
                            controller.play();
                          }
                        else{
                          print('============pause');
                          controller.pause();
                          }
                    },
                    child: CachedVideoPlayer(controller),
                  )
              ),
              Center(
                child: showheart
                    ? Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/gifs/heart.gif')
                )
                    : SizedBox()
              ),
              Center(
                  child: ispaused
                      ? Image(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/pause.png')
                  )
                      : SizedBox()
              )
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child:
//              circularProgress(),
              Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/gifs/loadermain.gif')
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    postcontroller.dispose();
  }
```

main page(preload pageview):

```
PreloadPageView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          controller: postscontroller,
          preloadPagesCount: 5,
          itemCount: posts.length,
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            Post post = posts[index];
            return post;
          });
```

Error:

```
 Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 336 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 0B until OOM, target footprint 402654152, growth limit 402653184" (VmSize 9519664 kB)
 on HeapTrim for 838.787ms
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Clamp target GC heap from 400MB to 384MB
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 384MB/384MB, paused 65us total 39.915ms
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 64KB allocation
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Clamp target GC heap from 400MB to 384MB
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
I/.imsunil.peopl(31137): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
utm=184 stm=54 core=6 HZ=100
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | stack=0x7106961000-0x7106963000 stackSize=1023KB
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | held mutexes=
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/31144/stack)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #00 pc 000000000008014c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #01 pc 000000000014b1f4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #02 pc 00000000005146c0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPool::GetTask(art::Thread*)+256)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #03 pc 0000000000513a4c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+144)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #04 pc 000000000051350c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+148)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #05 pc 00000000000e8930  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #06 pc 0000000000085094  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   (no managed stack frames)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] 
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] "Signal Catcher" prio=10 tid=5 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12c00078 self=0x71976f7000
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | sysTid=31149 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x710595ad50
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | state=S schedstat=( 978958 6594323 7 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=5 HZ=100
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | stack=0x7105864000-0x7105866000 stackSize=991KB
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | held mutexes=
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/31149/stack)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #00 pc 00000000000d3268  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+8)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #01 pc 0000000000090148  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (sigwait+68)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #02 pc 00000000004da1d0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::WaitForSignal(art::Thread*, art::SignalSet&)+392)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #03 pc 00000000004d8f50  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+268)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #04 pc 00000000000e8930  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #05 pc 0000000000085094  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   (no managed stack frames)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] 
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] "ADB-JDWP Connection Control Thread" prio=10 tid=8 WaitingInMainDebuggerLoop
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12c000f0 self=0x710526c800
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | sysTid=31150 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x710585dd50
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | state=S schedstat=( 6899537 3956038 15 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | stack=0x7105767000-0x7105769000 stackSize=991KB
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | held mutexes=
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/31150/stack)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #00 pc 00000000000d3168  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__ppoll+8)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #01 pc 000000000008dbec  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (poll+88)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #02 pc 0000000000008e24  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libadbconnection.so (adbconnection::AdbConnectionState::RunPollLoop(art::Thread*)+824)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #03 pc 000000000000721c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libadbconnection.so (adbconnection::CallbackFunction(void*)+1076)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #04 pc 00000000000e8930  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #05 pc 0000000000085094  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   (no managed stack frames)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] 
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] "ReferenceQueueDaemon" prio=10 tid=9 Waiting
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12c00168 self=0x7100bec000
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | sysTid=31152 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x70a8d95d50
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | state=S schedstat=( 45776091 76168070 359 ) utm=2 stm=2 core=6 HZ=100
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | stack=0x70a8c93000-0x70a8c95000 stackSize=1039KB
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | held mutexes=
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/31152/stack)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #00 pc 000000000008014c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #01 pc 000000000014b1f4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #02 pc 000000000040c0e4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+620)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #03 pc 000000000040db44  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+284)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   - waiting on <0x077da922> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:220)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   - locked <0x077da922> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:142)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] 
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] "FinalizerDaemon" prio=10 tid=10 WaitingForGcToComplete
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12c001e0 self=0x7100bedc00
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | sysTid=31153 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x70a8c8cd50
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | state=S schedstat=( 197406407 93751169 663 ) utm=15 stm=4 core=7 HZ=100
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | stack=0x70a8b8a000-0x70a8b8c000 stackSize=1039KB
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | held mutexes=
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/31153/stack)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #00 pc 000000000008014c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #01 pc 000000000014b1f4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #02 pc 0000000000243ecc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::WaitForGcToCompleteLocked(art::gc::GcCause, art::Thread*)+444)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #03 pc 0000000000248fdc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::CollectGarbageInternal(art::gc::collector::GcType, art::gc::GcCause, bool)+836)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #04 pc 000000000024d1d8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::AllocateInternalWithGc(art::Thread*, art::gc::AllocatorType, bool, unsigned long, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Class>*)+1196)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #05 pc 0000000000580ed4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artAllocObjectFromCodeInitializedRegionTLAB+376)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #06 pc 000000000013e078  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_alloc_object_initialized_region_tlab+104)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #07 pc 00000000020b5650  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize+368)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #08 pc 0000000000136334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #09 pc 0000000000144fec  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #10 pc 00000000002e2674  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+384)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #11 pc 00000000002dd8d4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+892)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #12 pc 000000000059ff90  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+648)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #13 pc 0000000000130814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #14 pc 00000000001b3bc2  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize+22)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #15 pc 00000000005a255c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1100)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #16 pc 0000000000130914  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #17 pc 00000000001b3cb4  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal+164)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #18 pc 00000000005a0250  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1352)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #19 pc 0000000000130814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #20 pc 00000000001b39b6  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+50)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #21 pc 00000000005a1a70  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1788)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #22 pc 0000000000130a14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #23 pc 00000000000ea9a0  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.Thread.run+8)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #24 pc 00000000002b3988  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.16775679700042528677+240)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #25 pc 00000000005914f8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #26 pc 000000000013f468  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #27 pc 0000000000136334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #28 pc 0000000000144fec  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #29 pc 00000000004afefc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #30 pc 00000000004b1010  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+416)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #31 pc 00000000004f19cc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1176)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #32 pc 00000000000e8930  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #33 pc 0000000000085094  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize(BinderInternal.java:63)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:294)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:281)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:142)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] 
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] "FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" prio=10 tid=11 Sleeping
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12c00288 self=0x7100bef800
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | sysTid=31154 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x70a8b83d50
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | state=S schedstat=( 1896305 12050676 28 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=6 HZ=100
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | stack=0x70a8a81000-0x70a8a83000 stackSize=1039KB
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | held mutexes=
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/31154/stack)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #00 pc 0000000000080150  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+32)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #01 pc 000000000014b62c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::TimedWait(art::Thread*, long, int)+168)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #02 pc 000000000040c0f8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+640)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #03 pc 000000000040db44  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+284)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native method)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   - sleeping on <0x0c558fb3> (a java.lang.Object)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:440)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   - locked <0x0c558fb3> (a java.lang.Object)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:356)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepForMillis(Daemons.java:388)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForFinalization(Daemons.java:416)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:328)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:142)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] 
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] "HeapTaskDaemon" prio=10 tid=12 WaitingForGcToComplete
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12c00308 self=0x7197712c00
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | sysTid=31151 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x70a8e9ed50
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | state=S schedstat=( 7529784650 1145399312 4822 ) utm=640 stm=112 core=7 HZ=100
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | stack=0x70a8d9c000-0x70a8d9e000 stackSize=1039KB
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | held mutexes=
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   kernel: (couldn't read(art::gc::Heap::WaitForGcToCompleteLocked(art::gc::GcCause, art::Thread*)+444)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #03 pc 00000000002504dc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::WaitForGcToComplete(art::gc::GcCause, art::Thread*)+412)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #04 pc 000000000025bf9c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ConcurrentGC(art::Thread*, art::gc::GcCause, bool)+68)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #05 pc 0000000000261bb0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ConcurrentGCTask::Run(art::Thread*)+36)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #06 pc 000000000028f8b0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*)+64)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:528)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:142)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] 
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] "Binder:31137_1" prio=10 tid=13 Native
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12c00380 self=0x70f4b4b800
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | sysTid=31155 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x70a897cd50
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | state=S schedstat=( 6275306 17591983 80 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=6 HZ=100
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | stack=0x70a8886000-0x70a8888000 stackSize=991KB
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | held mutexes=
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/31155/stack)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #00 pc 00000000000d3124  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #01 pc 000000000008bbd8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (ioctl+132)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #02 pc 0000000000059e58  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+244)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #03 pc 000000000005a034  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+24)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #04 pc 000000000005a80c  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+80)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #05 pc 0000000000080990  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #06 pc 00000000000135f0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+328)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #07 pc 00000000000c4ac0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #08 pc 00000000000e8930  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #09 pc 0000000000085094  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   (no managed stack frames)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] 
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630] "Binder:31137_2" prio=10 tid=14 Native
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12c003f8 self=0x710527e000
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | sysTid=31156 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x70a387fd50
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | state=S schedstat=( 19512649 30759737 112 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | stack=0x70a3789000-0x70a378b000 stackSize=991KB
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   | held mutexes=
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/31156/stack)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #00 pc 00000000000d3124  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #01 pc 000000000008bbd8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (ioctl+132)
F/.imsunil.peopl(31137): runtime.cc:630]   native: #02 pc 0000000000059e58  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+244)
F/libc    (31137): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 31137 (.imsunil.people), pid 31137 (.imsunil.people)
Process name is com.imsunil.people, not key_process
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Realme/RMX1851/RMX1851:10/QKQ1.190918.001/1590390095:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2020-07-21 20:35:13+0530
pid: 31137, tid: 31137, name: .imsunil.people  >>> com.imsunil.people <<<
uid: 10377
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallObjectMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw an exception; no stack trace available
(Throwable with no stack trace)
    in call to CallObjectMethodV
    from void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int)'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000079a1  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007ff94b0430
    x4  fefeff7093863f97  x5  fefeff7093863f97  x6  fefeff7093863f97  x7  7f7f7f7fffff7fff
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  c9437a093e9bd480  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000000000
    x12 fffffff0fffffbdf  x13 ffffffffffffffff  x14 0000000000000004  x15 ffffffffffffffff
    x16 00000071939008c8  x17 00000071938dc9a0  x18 0000007197db4000  x19 00000000000079a1
    x20 00000000000079a1  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 000000707eb46700  x23 0000007111118625
    x24 000000711113a189  x25 0000000000000001  x26 000000711173b258  x27 00000071976d16d0
    x28 0000007111643338  x29 0000007ff94b04d0
    sp  0000007ff94b0410  lr  000000719388c5ec  pc  000000719388c618
```

Comment: i got the same problem. Do share if you find any solution.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, Please do share if you have any solution for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you see the exception, you get the idea that your application is consuming plenty of RAM of the device.

You need to manage that memory leak in your flutter application.

Android and iOS OS allocate every application a limited amount of RAM in order to manage all processes at the same time.

If any of the applications use more RAM than their allocation, OS stops all processes of that application. and we see it as a crash.

In your case, you are playing multiple videos in your application, and all videos are caught videos. As they are caught videos, they are temporarily saved in RAM, and as you see more and more videos, you are using more and more RAM.

You need to optimize your application, you can clear video after page changes.

With that, you can control your memory leak.

Comment: @Devaesh Ranpara Thankyou very much for answering my issue,  can you please tell me, how can I remove cache stored at some particular order of pages like pagenumber 5, 10 or like after scrolling to the next page like that.

Comment: Hi sunil,
Can you please share whole code so i can provide you exact answer.

Comment: please check this https://gist.github.com/snlsmrt/779291b65cc4a1f66e6b98c9cae6196f

Comment: @I'mSunil3 do you have any update? I'm in the same situation

Comment: Try using listview.builder and make sure to create a video_player widget which basically gets disposed off when it goes off the screen.

Comment: @MaheshJamdade this is only the case when using addAutomaticKeepAlives: false